# Correct Resolution size for Web in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop

I want to ask whats the resolution size (Best Resolution size) for Web.

Is it 800 (Height) X 600 (Width) or 800 (Width) X 600 (Height)?

Looked online for directives and I am not being able to get a good directives here.

Comment: Your question is off-topic as it does not relate to scripting, programming or tools used for that purpose. You would be better off asking on the [Graphic Deisgn Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: try applying `800 (Height) X 600 (Width)` to an image in landscape format and you know the answer...

Answer (score 1):

As most web based media is in landscape mode, I would go with 800(width) x 600 (height).
Standard convention for sizing especially on the web is width x height e.g 1080p = 1080x720, etc.

To provide some more detail, the best resolution depends on the requirements of your project and a few other factors (e.g. how fast you want the website hosting the image to load, what media would be used to view the content - Computer, or mobile devices, etc.)

View this link for some more info on resolutions: https://digital-photography-school.com/image-size-and-resolution-explained-for-print-and-onscreen/
Hope that clarifies it a bit.

Cheers!